# Ruby time subtraction

Tags: ruby

There is the following task: I need to get minutes between one time and another one: for example, between "8:15" and "7:45". I have the following code:

```
(Time.parse("8:15") - Time.parse("7:45")).minute
```

But I get result as "108000.0 seconds".

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

The result you get back is a float of the number of seconds not a Time object. So to get the number of minutes and seconds between the two times:

```
require 'time'
t1 = Time.parse("8:15")
t2 = Time.parse("7:45")
total_seconds = (t1 - t2) # => 1800.0

minutes = (total_seconds / 60).floor # => 30
seconds = total_seconds.to_i % 60 # => 0

puts "difference is #{minutes} minute(s) and #{seconds} second(s)"
```

Using `floor` and modulus (`%`) allows you to split up the minutes and seconds so it's more human readable, rather than having '6.57 minutes'

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid weird time parsing gotchas (Daylight Saving, running the code around midnight) by simply doing some math on the hours and minutes instead of parsing them into `Time` objects. Something along these lines (I'd verify the math with tests):

```
one = "8:15"
two = "7:45"
h1, m1 = one.split(":").map(&:to_i)
h2, m2 = two.split(":").map(&:to_i)
puts (h1 - h2) * 60 + m1 - m2
```

If you do want to take Daylight Saving into account (e.g. you sometimes want an extra hour added or subtracted depending on today's date) then you will need to involve `Time`, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Time subtraction returns the value in seconds. So divide by 60 to get the answer in minutes:

```
=> (Time.parse("8:15") - Time.parse("7:45")) / 60
#> 30.0
```

Comment: As a time code paranoiac, there are some gotchas here to be aware of: This code won't work across day boundaries, e.g. 00:01 - 23:59. It can fail if the code runs at midnight – it might parse the first time on the last millisecond of Monday and the second time on the first millisecond of Tuesday, for example. It will probably exhibit strange behavior for some time ranges on days when Daylight Saving changes.